# How to prove and define amount of countably infinite set in the naturals numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, cardinals

I have the following question
[Picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrB0b.jpg)

What is the cardinality of $D=\{A \subseteq \Bbb N \mid \vert A \vert = \aleph_0 \land \vert \Bbb N \setminus A \vert = \aleph_0 \}$?

I do understand that A could be N even, or N odd for example
But how do I find the amount of Countably infinite sets in N?
I can’t think of more than just N odd and N even, but I’m not sure how to prove that they are the only countably infinite sets inside the natural numbers

Edit - I thought now and I understand I could also define A as {2, 3 ….} and so on, so there are infinite possibilities to build such set.
How do I define that cardinality?

Comment: Well, they aren't the only ones, so...

Comment: yeah, I just edited because I understoond I could also do A= {1,2,4,5,6...} and so forth with skipping a number, or starting the count from somewhere else. but then how can I define its cardiniality?

Comment: Assuming you know some basic facts about cardinal arithmetic, the easiest way to calculate this cardinality is to determine how many finite subsets $\Bbb N$ has and also to figure out how many cofinite subsets (i.e., subsets with finite complements) $\Bbb N$ has.  Anything that's neither finite nor cofinite is in $D$.  You will find that $D$ has many, many sets.  For example, the set of primes is in $D$.

Comment: so my line if thinking right now is this: the sets that can be in D are primes, even/odd, and pretty much Modular set of every natural number, so I think that maybe I should constructe an injection P(N) --> D. but Im not sure how to construct such function

Comment: Hint: Fix a set $E\in D$. Then every infinite subset of $E$ is an element of $D$...